# Typescript - Front - I want static imports merged, but dynamic imports not merged

Tags: typescript, dynamic, import, static, es6-modules

I want to merge some files (those with static import), but some don't have to be merged (those with dynamic import).

How can I tell that to typescript ?

The demo is done with 4 files, one index with the main() function, and 3 classes A, B and C.

Current typescript config :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "old"
  ]
}
```

src/index.ts

```
'use strict';
//@ts-check

import { C } from './c/c'; // I want this one to be merged in index

export const main = async () => {
  const c = new C();
  c.log();
}

main();
```

src/c.ts

```
'use strict';
//@ts-check

import { B } from '../b/b'; // I want this one to be merged in c, so in index

export class C {

  async log() {
    const A = await import('/' + 'a.js');
    const a = new A();
    a.log();
    const b = new B();
    b.log();
  }
}
```

src/b.ts

```
'use strict';
//@ts-check

export class B {

  async log() {
    console.log('b');
  }
}
```

src/a.ts

```
'use strict';
//@ts-check

export class A {

  log() {
    console.log('a');
  }
}
```

Currently I get :

```
- lib/a/a.js
- lib/b/b.js
- lib/c/c.js
- lib/index.js
```

But I would like :

```
- lib/a.js // Apart from index, because it is dynamically imported
- lib/index.js
```

Any idea ?

Is there any decorator to tell typescript to merge c and b into index, then put a aside index ?

As possible, I'd like to not have to add any build layer (such webpack), and stay with just typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure there's no way to do this with just the TypeScript compiler.  (You can manually merge groups of files using project references and `outFile`, but you'd still need an AMD or SystemJS module runtime.)  You'll need to use a separate tool such as Webpack.  IMO that's as it should be, but the opinion that matters is that of the TypeScript team.

Comment: I'm currently checking if Rollup.js fits my needs.